# ach so + Adjektiv

Tags: adjective, adverb

> Ich spüre deine **ach so** heftigen Schläge nicht mal!

What does "ach so" here mean? Does it add sarcasm to the sentence?

Comment: Yes, it is similar to "[oh-so](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26456/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-the-oh-so-adjective-idiom)" in English.

Answer (score 1):

You sensed it correctly, that *ach so* is a modal particle in that sentence. It belittles the effort.

Comment: why "modal particle" ? It is an extension of "so", which is a degree modifier for the adjective